# Is there an Organization schema type for hobby groups?

Tags: schema.org

Is there a way to specify Schema.org [`Organization` markup](http://schema.org/Organization) for a small group and not as a business?  I'm trying to create structured data for hobby groups.  However the list of types seem to be limited.

The specified types are:

- `Airline`
- `Corporation`
- `EducationalOrganization`
- `GovernmentOrganization`
- `LocalBusiness`
- `MedicalOrganization`
- `NGO`
- `PerformingGroup`
- `SportsOrganization`

Types available in extensions are:

- `Consortium`
- `LibrarySystem`
- `NewsMediaOrganization`
- `WorkersUnion`

Of those, is `Consortium` the only thing that makes sense for a small group such as a group of hobbyist?

Have I missed a completely different schema that would work better than `Organization`?

Or is it more likely that no schemas exist that make sense at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Organization` subtype that makes sense for hobbyist groups **in general**, so use the `Organization` type itself.

Of course, if the hobbyist group has a **specific purpose/background** that matches one of the subtypes, use this subtype. For example, a cone club could use `SportsOrganization`; a choir could use `MusicGroup`.

The proposed `Consortium` type is intended for organizations whose members *typically* are organizations itself, so it doesn’t seem to apply in your case. I’d only use this type if the group is named, or referred to as, *consortium*.

Comment: Oh, so you don't actually need to use a specific type inside of a top level Schema?

Comment: @Maelish: What do you mean with "top level Schema"? If you mean top-level items specified in the structured data on your page: *every* item should have a type. If you mean top-level types in the Schema.org vocabulary: there are only two: `DataType` (typically shouldn’t be used) and `Thing` :) And it’s perfectly fine to use `Thing`, namely if no other more specific type (like `Organization`, `Person` etc.) matches. *Everything* (objects, concepts, beings, etc.) is a `Thing`. But always use the most specific type available (every type inherits all its parent types).

Comment: What I mean, is that Organization doesn't need a subtype.  That seems to be what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Maelish: Yes, correct. There’s nothing special about `Organization`, it’s a type like any other. Simple rule really: start at `Thing` and go down the hierarchy as far as possible.